# Using java if-else

Tags: java, if-statement

This is my first time to use stack overflow to ask a question. I'm a beginner of Java programming. I was stuck on my assignment, can anyone help me to solve?

So, the problem is using java if-else to write the contents on the image into java code. But I didn't get the question. Can anyone explain? Is it possible to code using if-else? Thank you.

[image]

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class MailOrderHouse{

    public static void main(String[] args){

       Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
       double product1;
       double product2;
       double product3;
       double product4;
       double product5;

       System.out.println("Product price: ");
       double product_price = sc.nextDouble();

       System.out.println("Enter quantity sold: ");
       int quantity = sc.nextInt();

    }
}
```

I totally don't understand the question.

Comment: What have you done to resolve the query? SO isn't a site to do your homework for you

Comment: Please refer this https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @AkshayKatariya thanks for helping me to learn how to ask question on stack overflow

Comment: This: `double product_price = sc.nextLine();` isn't going to work for you. You need: `double product_price = sc.nextDouble();` Display a list of products with price shown first and allow the User to choose a product number. The price for that product should be related to the product number (don't ask for price). Ask for quantity wanted. Do the summation.

Comment: Ok, as far as I understand your question, If else condition will be considered to use if there is to be judged. In your case, I think there is no need for you to use it. you just need to scan the entered product id of the user then you should calculate the prices with the quantity to show the result. then that's it. your assignment will be done.

Comment: @AlexisVillar I feel confused is because it said "calculate the total price for the products sold", if it just using scanner, I can solve it easy. But below it said "provide 2 sets of result", and also my lecturer just finish to taught us using if-else, so the assignment should be using if-else. that's why I feel confused.

Comment: @DevilsHnd thanks for reminded. but I have confused on how should I write my code, so I stopped editing sc.nextDouble() 

I feel confused to this question is because I need to use if-else to write. I got you. but I think it is not the solution for me. still, thank you

Comment: Oh! Okay. Now I get it. That's what I have said above. That if-else condition is used for judgment. So What have you tried so far? 

I don't know what should be the parameters or variables you were going to use on your condition. but this could help you. a simpler to understand IF-ELSE Condition.
[link]https://zellwk.com/blog/js-if-else/[link]

Comment: @AlexisVillar I know how to use if-else condition, but I just feeling confused to this exercise question. how can I write this exercise as java code? the expected output must be "Mail-order house sell 2 product2 for RM9.00". So, which should be user input? the user is seller, not buyer. if the output just need to calculate the total price, I will use the price*quantity sold. but now it want to use if else to output "Mail-order house sell 2 product2 for RM9.00."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, indicate to User the products available and their respective price:

```
int productChoice = 0;
int quantity = 0;
double totalSum = 0.0;

System.out.println("Welcome To The Mail_Order House.");
System.out.println("Please select Product Number (1 to 5) you want to buy:\n");

System.out.println("1) Product Name 1: RM2.98");
System.out.println("2) Product Name 2: RM4.50");
System.out.println("3) Product Name 3: RM9.98");
System.out.println("4) Product Name 4: RM4.49");
System.out.println("5) Product Name 5: RM6.87");
```

This allows the User to easily see what is available to buy and therefore make a valid choice. Now ask the User to enter a product number:

```
productChoice = sc.nextInt();
```

The value the User supplies relates to the product name he/she wants. Now it's just a matter of asking the User the desired quantity of that specific product:

```
System.out.println("What quantity of Product #" + productChoice + " do you want?");
quantity = sc.nextInt();
```

Now that we have the product quantity it's a matter using **IF/ELSE IF** to gather the price of that selected product and multiply it by the User supplied quantity to achieve the total sum owed for that product:

```
if (productChoice == 1) {
    // ......TO DO........
}
else if (productChoice == 2) {
    totalSum += 4.50 * quantity;
    // This is the same as: totalSum = totalSum + (4.50 * quantity);
}
else if (productChoice == 3) {
    // ......TO DO........
}
else if (productChoice == 4) {
    // ......TO DO........
}
else if (productChoice == 5) {
    // ......TO DO........
}
else {
    System.out.println("Invalid product number supplied!");
}
```

As you can see, you now have all the required data to display the required output String to Console:

```
System.out.println("Mail-Order House sold " + quantity + 
                   " of Product #" + productChoice + " for: RM" + 
                   String.format("%.2f", totalSum));
```

The `String.format("%.2f", totalSum)` in the above line ensures a precision of 2 decimal places in the total sum is displayed to console. You wouldn't want a number like: `21.422000522340` to be displayed as a monetary value in this particular case (read up on the [String.format()](https://www.javatpoint.com/java-string-format) method).

Comment: Appreciated! it really help me to understand. My problem has been solved.

Answer (score 1):

You have to take 5 inputs for number of products sold & 5 inputs for product prices. You have to calculate the total price of these products. Instead of taking 10 variables for 10 inputs you can just use a loop like:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class MailOrderHouse{

    public static void main(String[] args){

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        double total = 0;
        int totalProduct = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            int productQuantity = sc.nextInt();
            double productPrice = sc.nextDouble();
            total += productPrice;
            totalProduct += productQuantity;
        }
        System.out.println("Mail-order house sell " + totalProduct + " product " + totalProduct + " for RM" + productPrice); 
    }
}
```

Couldn't understand your input format though. Hope it helps.

Comment: Is it possible to force to only use scanner and if-else without for loop to write this?